# Setting a folder type with Exchange Web Service API

Tags: java, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to create global folders in a Exchange 2010 server that are to be used by the users. If I am right I have to set a specific folder type (in my case contacts)so that the users are able to save contacts in these folders. For this, I am using the 
I am using the EWSJava 1.1.5. My problem is that I cannot find a way to do this, respectively cannot find a class to manage this for me. Can anybody help me out? Many thanks in advance.

Regards,
Bene